# Access Cassandra Via Network Load Balancer(AWS) in different AWS account

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I have installed cassandra(three nodes) on kubernetes in aws account.

I want to open the same cassandra via aws endpoint(through NLB) to different aws account so that i can access this cassandra for read/write purpose.

I am using spark(in different AWS account) to load data in cassandra but i am getting this WARN while loading the data.

`WARN ChannelPool: [s0|/10.0.246.140:32034]  Error while opening new channel (ConnectionInitException: [s0|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (STARTUP {CQL_VERSION=3.0.0, DRIVER_NAME=DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R), DRIVER_VERSION=4.7.2, CLIENT_ID=b52c9022-561a-48d3-bd98-893c6c17f0c3, APPLICATION_NAME=Spark-Cassandra-Connector-application_1606197155514_0510}): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException))`

Has anybody open Cassandra via NLB , do i need to make separate routes for each node in cassandra in NLB? if yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a K8s service and expose it through an [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) such as Traefik so clients (such as your Spark app) can connect to your Cassandra cluster from outside the Kubernetes cluster.

If you're using the [**DataStax Cassandra Operator**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cass-operator/doc/cass-operator/cassOperatorTOC.html) (**cass-operator**), it makes it a lot easier since it comes pre-configured with a service that you can use. See the Ingress examples we have included in [Connecting to Cassandra from outside the Kubernetes cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cass-operator/doc/cass-operator/cassOperatorConnectToK8sFromOutsideCluster.html).

If you weren't already aware, have a look at open-source **[K8ssandra](https://k8ssandra.io/)**. It is a ready-made platform for running Apache Cassandra in Kubernetes using the DataStax Cassandra Operator under the hood but with all the tools bundled together:

- [Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/docs/) for automated repairs
- [Medusa](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-medusa/wiki) for backups and restores
- [Metrics Collector](https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra) for monitoring with Prometheus + Grafana
- Traefik templates for k8s cluster ingress

Since all these components are open-source, they are all free to use and don't require a licence or paid subscription but still comes with a robust community support. Cheers!

Comment: I have opened cassandra through Kong(NLB), i am able to connect cassandra from outside aws account. But when i connect to cassandra it connects to one node and start writing to it but it gives above WARN as it cannot establish connection to other nodes. As these IP's are not accessible from other AWS account.

Current architecture:

Spark application --> AWS Endpoint --> AWS endpoint service --> NLB --> Kong(ingress) --> Service --> Pod.

How to make sure spark will connect to each node in cassandra ?